# Ajax code works for all browser, except firefox?

Tags: javascript, ajax

```
function verledenFunction() {
  var verleden = document.getElementById("tarot1").src;
  // document.getElementById("verledenAntwoord").innerHTML = "hoi dit is een modal test";

  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else {
    // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  } 
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("verledenAntwoord").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;      
    }
  }

  xmlhttp.open("GET","tarotantwoord.php?q="+verleden,true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: Do you get an error? What happens?

Comment: Is `verleden` an URL?

Comment: Please don't post a URL to the problem. Create a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) here on Stack Overflow so we can analyze it here. If you fix your site then others who come here later won't be able to see what was wrong.

Comment: Sorry, found the problem. I am sending the source of an image and i am searching in the database for it. Firefox uses. www and chrome only the stuff that comes after the www.